# How to create auto update trigger for MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I've got table with products (changes dynamically) and table for data export. I need a trigger which once a day will add new products from table products into table export. Mine code is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER auto_update
BEFORE UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW
SET export.name = product.prod_name, export.link=product.prod_link, export.price=product.prod_price
WHERE product.prod_type='product';
```

But this code don't works. How to fix it? Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need an event rather than a trigger.

Comment: Maybe event, I'm quite new in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want this code to execute on scheduled basis, you may want to use the Event Scheduler instead.

Please see here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

From this you can do things like:

```
CREATE EVENT e_store_ts
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 10 SECOND
    DO
      INSERT INTO myschema.mytable VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
```

This will create a new event to execute every 10 seconds and insert a unix time stamp into table `mytable`. You can alter events with `ALTER` and you can drop them with `DROP`. Have fun!

So in your case create an event that executes every day, that performs the expression you wish to execute (DO clause).

Comment: And how to add only new items without re-entering whole table? As far as I understood there is a command `WHERE NOT EXISTS` but if I modify my code like this `INSERT INTO `export_copy`(`name`, `link`) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT p.post_title, p.guid FROM wp_posts p WHERE p.post_type='product')` I've got an error which says that syntax is incorrect near `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Do have a lot of products and are you adding a lot daily?

Comment: Not much, but I'm lazy one. I'd like to create script now and forget about it :)

Comment: I've managed create event for products update. Event's code is:  
`INSERT INTO export_copy(name, link) 
SELECT p.post_title, p.guid 
FROM wp_posts p 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM export_copy, wp_posts
    WHERE export_copy.id=wp_posts.ID)`